# IIS 10 - ARR - Use External Cache - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: iis, caching, windows-server-2016, arr

Windows 2016 Server / IIS 10 / ARR
**Use External Cache** > **Value does not fall within the expected range**

When I enable
[x]**Use external cache**
**File Share Path**: \\Cache01\Caching
Then set either
**Worker process**
(OR)
**Specific user**

Click on [**Apply**]
I get this error.

> Server Affinity
>   There was an error while performing this operation.
>   Detail:
>   Value does not fall within the expected range.

I then added the same user as the [**Identity**] of the application pool.
And still the same error.

I checked the Event Viewer, and there is nothing listed for this error.

I am following the instructions on this link here.
[Using Multiple Instances of Application Request Routing (ARR) Servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/using-multiple-instances-of-application-request-routing-arr-servers)

Everything is ready; I just need to get this part done.
Thanks for any assistance anyone can give me.

Comment: Have you checked whether the domain account have permission to access the fileshare folder? It is recommended to use process monitor to trace this issue.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon

Comment: Yes, the user has permission. I was never able to figure this one out, and neither could the people over at IIS Forum. One of the guys told me to do without the cache, and that is what I am doing for now.
However, I would like to have a caching server setup in the forest. I feel that it would really help to get the content to the visitors faster than it already is.